# fscanf() returns negative value

Tags: c, windows, winapi, scanf

I am using fscanf() function to read data line by line from a text file. It was functioning fine but suddenly I don't know what mistake I made and now the function returns a negative value. 
below is my code snippet:

```
FILE *fp;
char ip[16];
int port;
fp = fopen("ClientInformation.txt", "r");
int size = -1;
while (!feof(fp))
{
    fgetc(fp);
    size++;
}
char buff[1000];
sprintf(buff,"%i",size);
MessageBox(NULL,
           buff,
           "Size",
           MB_ICONINFORMATION);

if(size > 0)
{
    while (fscanf(fp, " %s %d", ip, &port) > 0)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,"fscanf() Successful","SUCCESS!", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }
}
```

Comment: the negative value is probably an error code, and if not check the errno variable...

Comment: Um, isn't your `while (!feof(fp))` loop putting `fp` at `EOF`?

Comment: Assuming it even opened at all (which is never checked).

Comment: never ever use feof() in look break condition

Comment: contd.... i suggest whenever you call a function that is supposed to return some value...always check for return value...for example fopen()....you have not checked if it returned ok...what if file is not present?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might like to add this call

```
rewind(fp);
```

just before

```
while (fscanf(fp, " %s %d", ip, &port) > 0)
{
```

Also one should always check the result of system calls. In your case mainly whether `fopen()` really did return something different from `NULL`.

Addtionally the `while(!feof(fp))` construct mostly likely wouldn't always behave as expected ([Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/694576)). You'd be better off going the way proposed by *WhozCraig* in the comment(s) below.

Comment: Or better still, just throw out the first while and use fseek/ftell/fseek. A one-char-at-a-time fread seems a bit obtuse just to determine a file size =P

Comment: Thanks a ot everyone :).
Adding rewind(fp) solved the problem, but I am not still clear how did that happen. I am new in all this, please explain if you can.

Comment: @AyeshaHassan: Regarding what `rewind()` does you might like to read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fes6c2yd(v=vs.110).aspx having understood this you perhaps see what made it necessary to call `rewind()`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to determine the file size in advance. Just `fscanf()` the file and check the return value:

```
int ret;

while ((ret = fscanf(fp, " %s %d", ip, &port)) == 2) {
    MessageBox(NULL,"fscanf() Successful","SUCCESS!", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}

switch (ret) {
    case EOF:
        /* EOF or error, check errno */
        break;
    case 0:
    case 1:
        /* bogus file contents */
        break;
    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "Philip says this cannot happen, but it did.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Also: always check the return value of function calls.